# Dynamic lambda expression for SingleOrDefault

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-expressions

I have a `DataClassesDataContext` containing a group of tables, and I am trying to do `lambda expression` filtering dynamically using only the name of the tables and the names of the fields. Basically I want to find for each table if a row with a specific ID already exists.

If I knew the table ahead of time, I would use :

```
if (dataClassesDataContext.MYTABLEXs.SingleOrDefault(m => m.MYTABLEX_ID == MyId)) 
    DoExists();
```

But as I am getting tables names MYTABLEX and MYTABLEY (and fields names MYTABLEX_ID and MYTABLEY_ID) as strings on the fly, I am trying to build the above filter at runtime.

I can access the table dynamically using :

```
Type tableType = Type.GetType(incommingtableName); // incommingtableName being looped over MYTABLEX, MYTABLEY , ...
var dbTable = dataClassesDataContext.GetTable(tableType);
```

But then I am stuck. How can I build a lambda expression that will behave something like :

```
if (dbTable.SingleOrDefault(m => m.incommingtableName_id == MyId)) 
    DoExists();
```

Any idea ?

Comment: You can build them with [Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class that allows you to build expression dynamically in runtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build an expression in runtime. And also you would need to have generic version of `SingleOrDefault` method. Here is example:

```
Type tableType = typeof (incommingtableName); // table type
string idPropertyName = "ID"; // id property name
int myId = 42; // value for searching

// here we are building lambda expression dynamically. It will be like m => m.ID = 42;
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(tableType, "m"); 
MemberExpression idProperty = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, idPropertyName);
ConstantExpression constValue = Expression.Constant(myId);

BinaryExpression body = Expression.Equal(idProperty, constValue);

var lambda = Expression.Lambda(body, param);


// then we would need to get generic method. As SingleOrDefault is generic method, we are searching for it,
// and then construct it based on tableType parameter

// in my example i've used CodeFirst context, but it shouldn't matter
SupplyDepot.DAL.SupplyDepotContext context = new SupplyDepotContext();
var dbTable = context.Set(tableType);


// here we are getting SingleOrDefault<T>(Expression) method and making it as SingleOrDefault<tableType>(Expression)
var genericSingleOrDefaultMethod =
    typeof (Queryable).GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == "SingleOrDefault" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2);
var specificSingleOrDefault = genericSingleOrDefaultMethod.MakeGenericMethod(tableType);

// and finally we are exexuting it with constructed lambda
var result = specificSingleOrDefault.Invoke(null, new object[] { dbTable, lambda });
```

As possible optimization constructed lambda can be cached, so we wont need to build it each time, but it should work the same