# Calling async on Invoke produces CancellationToken error

Tags: c#, async-await, cancellation-token

I'm creating a generic async update method for Entity Framework 6.x on .NET Framework 4.8. Here's the class:

```
public class GenericUpdate<TEntity, TId, TDto>
    where TEntity : class
    where TId : IConvertible
    where TDto : class
{
    public async Task UpdateSingleAsync(string searchPropertyName, TId searchPropertyValue, TDto dto)
    {
        try
        {
            var tableType = typeof(TEntity);

            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30029230/dynamic-lambda-expression-for-singleordefault
            var param = Expression.Parameter(tableType, "m");
            var searchProperty = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, searchPropertyName);
            var constSearchValue = Expression.Constant(searchPropertyValue);

            var body = Expression.Equal(searchProperty, constSearchValue);

            var lambda = Expression.Lambda(body, param);

            using (var context = new MyContext())
            {
                var dbTable = context.Set(tableType);

                var genericSingleOrDefaultAsyncMethod =
                    typeof(QueryableExtensions).GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == "SingleOrDefaultAsync" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2);
                var specificSingleOrDefaultAsync = genericSingleOrDefaultAsyncMethod.MakeGenericMethod(tableType);

                // https://stackoverflow.com/a/16153317/177416
                var result = (Task<TEntity>) specificSingleOrDefault.Invoke(null, new object[] { dbTable, lambda });
                await result;

                context.Entry(result).CurrentValues.SetValues(dto);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

On the `result`, it blows up with:

> System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression  [System.Func[MyEntities.Models.SomeEntity,System.Boolean]]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Threading.CancellationToken'.

How do you call `Invoke` on an async method? What am I doing wrong?

**Update 1:** I used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16153317/177416) to add the (Task) to my code but obviously I'm doing something wrong.

**Update 2:** Following @StephenCleary, made this change:

```
dynamic dbTable = context.Set(tableType);
var result = await QueryableExtensions.SingleOrDefaultAsync(dbTable, lambda);
```

The first suggestion didn't work as `dbTable` didn't have a `SingleOrDefaultAsync`.

Now getting this error:

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.SingleOrDefaultAsync(System.Linq.IQueryable, System.Threading.CancellationToken)' has some invalid arguments

**Update 3 & solution:** Thanks to @StephenCleary, this solution works like a charm:

```
dynamic lambda = Expression.Lambda(body, param);

using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    dynamic dbTable = context.Set(tableType);
    var result = await QueryableExtensions.SingleOrDefaultAsync(dbTable, lambda);

    if(result != null)
    {
        context.Entry(result).CurrentValues.SetValues(dto);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: See: [How do you call invoke on an async method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153047/net-invoke-async-method-and-await)

Comment: @Wyck, that's where I got the `(Task<TEntity>)` code and it's exactly what I'm doing, isn't it? Please see my update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> generic async update method

I do have to question whether one horribly complex method is really more maintainable than a half-dozen or so clean and obvious methods.

That said, the error you're getting indicates you're retrieving the wrong overload of `SingleOrDefaultAsync`. Indeed, the code `typeof(QueryableExtensions).GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == "SingleOrDefaultAsync" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2)` just returns the first method of that name that has two parameters. This is an insufficient amount of information to ensure you get the correct method.

You can either add more checks to ensure the parameters are the types you expect, or you can just drop the reflection completely, since it doesn't appear to be necessary:

```
var dbTable = context.Set(tableType);
var result = await dbTable.SingleOrDefaultAsync(lambda);
```

This is assuming that `dbTable` is of an appropriate type. If it's some unspecified type (e.g., `object`), you can still use the compiler's overload resolution by making it `dynamic`:

```
dynamic dbTable = context.Set(tableType);
var result = await QueryableExtensions.SingleOrDefaultAsync(dbTable, lambda);
```

Comment: Now getting the error indicated in Update 2 above, @StephenCleary.

Comment: Try making the `lambda` `dynamic`.

Comment: Thanks, @StephenCleary, that worked. But why? What is `dynamic` doing here?

Comment: Lambda expressions in reflection are weird. The [overload you're trying to call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.singleordefaultasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_QueryableExtensions_SingleOrDefaultAsync__1_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0_System_Boolean___) has type `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` but `lambda` is of type `LambdaExpression`. So `dynamic` is doing "magic compiler stuff". I don't even know.